# Winter 23 - ICU date Formats - Date.parse

Tags: apex, date, winter23

I have observed in the last few days the following (locale = `en_US`):

```
Date d = Date.parse('15/56/2023');  // run with api V55
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,d);

Environment        ICU enabled?     Result
  Summer 22            N            TypeException - invalid date
  Summer 22            Y            TypeException - invalid date
  Winter 23            Y            Valid - 2024-04-25
  Winter 23            N            TypeException - invalid date
```

Is this an SFDC-introduced bug or feature?

*detected in my daily unit test runs; code that had been working for months/years, now failing regtests*

Possibly [related KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001cWwaQAE&title=date-parse-fails-with-1-digit-day-d-format-it-only-accept-the-day-format-as-2-digits-dd)

Comment: I don't know if this is definitive or not, but Salesforce may be aware of the issue because of their Apex Hammer Test system (see [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.apex_hammer_execution_status.htm&type=5) for how you can check your org's results). Still, I'd advise contacting support regarding this, the docs don't say anything about this behavior, and it's clearly new behavior, and not even JavaScript does this...

Comment: I suspect this is overflowing the parsed month and day components to arrive at the resulting "valid" date. E.g. 12/31/2023 plus the extra 3 months from `15/` gives 03/31/2024. Then add on the remaining 25 days from `/56/` works out at 04/25/2024. 
I'll ask internally what sort of overflow is occurring here and why.

Comment: This came out of a fix to the known issue [[Winter'23] Date.parse fails with 1 digit day (d) format, it only accept the day format as 2 digits (dd)](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001cWwaQAE). I'm following up with the globalization and localization teams on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This came out of a fix to the known issue - [Winter'23 - Date.parse fails with 1 digit day (d) format, it only accept the day format as 2 digits (dd)](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001cWwaQAE). I'm following up with the globalization and localization teams on this to ensure it is resolved.

The new Known Issue [No exception occurs when parsing an invalid date (e.g. 2/31/2022) with Date.parse() method on ICU enabled orgs since Winter'23(240)](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001wrNAQAY) was created to track the fix.

Comment: apparently, this is now fixed  per the KI so accepting answer