# Date.parse parses weird dates with no typeException

Tags: apex, date

Date.parse('30/30/2019') works different in sandboxes. Everywhere typeException is thrown as expected, but in one sandbox this date is being parsed into 2021-06-30 00:00:00.
I checked everything - api version, locale, release, excluded a duplicate of the Date class, tried super strange dates, an explicit call to System.Date.parse - I have nothing.
[image]

[image]

Obviously, 30 months are parsed into 2.5 years in a weird sandbox. What could be the reason?

Comment: Is ["Winter 23 - ICU date Formats - Date.parse"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/387249/winter-23-icu-date-formats-date-parse) possibly related?

Comment: I have seen similar issues (with Date.parse and incorrect date) approx 4-5 years ago. I simply decided to do not use that method since it is based on current users's locale

Comment: @FelixvanHove ICU Locale Formats are NOT enabled in both environments. It seems to me that this should exclude this relation.

Comment: Is the release update for ICU maybe not enabled, but the test run enabled? Else you can look for the `enableICULocaleDateFormat` flag in the LanguageSettings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the corresponding answer to [Winter 23 - ICU date Formats - Date.parse](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/388415/102). There are two related known issues around the functionality of Date.parse, that include the identified overflow bug.

> This came out of a fix to the known issue - Winter'23 - Date.parse fails with 1 digit day (d) format, it only accept the day format as 2 digits (dd). I'm following up with the globalization and localization teams on this to ensure it is resolved.
> The new Known Issue No exception occurs when parsing an invalid date (e.g. 2/31/2022) with Date.parse() method on ICU enabled orgs since Winter'23(240) was created to track the fix.